# Why does calling allEvents work from the Truffle console, but not from my application?

Tags: web3js, truffle, events

I am trying to retrieve the events associated with the default MetaCoin contract in Truffle. I am able to do this from the Truffle console, but not from within `app.js`. I am using Truffle 4.0.1 with Webpack and TestRPC. The abbreviated version of the contract is as follows:

```
contract MetaCoin {
    mapping (address => uint) balances;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    function MetaCoin() {
        balances[tx.origin] = 10000;
    }

    function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) returns(bool sufficient) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return false;
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
        return true;
    }
}
```

In the project's app.js, I do the following when using sendCoin to verify that the event is working.

```
MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  meta = instance;
  return meta.sendCoin(receiver, amount, {from: account});
}).then(function(tx) {
  self.setStatus("Transaction complete!");
  console.log("the transaction:", tx);
});
```

When I view a transaction in the browser Javascript console I can verify that the transaction object does indeed have have an entry under `logs` with `_from`, `_to`, and `_value` so this seems to be working. The problem I am having is using `allEvents` from the Javascript API to get all past events. In my app.js, I have added an additional function:

```
fetchLogs: function() {
var self = this;
var meta;
var event_data;
var event_data2;
MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  meta = instance;
  console.log("working");
  var events = meta.allEvents({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
  events.get(function(error, log) {
    event_data = log;
    console.log(event_data);
  });
});
```

},

When I view the browser console, I get the message "working" and then `undefined` where I should get an object with all of the past logs.

However, by using the same Javascript in the Truffle Console, I am able to see the logs by doing the following process:

```
> var meta;
> MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) { meta = instance});
> var events = meta.allEvents({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
> var event_data;
> events.get( (error, log) => {event_data = log;});
> event_data;
```

When I do this in the Truffle Console I get the a list of objects corresponding to every transaction that's been performed so far. So why does this work in the console, and not on my Truffle application?

Comment: Did you check if error has additional information?

Comment: It seems like that part of the code isn't even getting executed. I added another console.log() within the callback, and it appears that it never gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using MetaMask injected web3?

I had the exact same problem and then found this [issue](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/2393) on github.

Turns out if I change my code not to use injected web3 but a local one I can fetch events. So this seems to be an issue of MetaMask.

Hope this also fixes your problem...it took me almost 2 days to realize it was related to MetaMask.

Comment: I am using Metamask injected web3. This appears to match my issue exactly. Unfortunately it doesn't look like there is a guaranteed fix, but now I know what to try. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I just fixed this for now by not using injected web3.